# Display formatted DateTime inside ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, date, datetime, parsing, time

Into `DataGrid` I have 2 column:

```
public string DayName {get; set;}    
public DateTime DateTimeColumn {get; set;}
```

I want to display data as below:

```
DayName   | DateTimeColumn  
Monday    | 2018-09-03 
Tuesday   | 2018-09-04 
Wednesday | 2019-09-05 
....
```

To do that I have method:

```
public static ObservableCollection<MyDataConcept> BuildDataConceptList(int year, int month)
{
   ObservableCollection<MyDataConcept> resultList = 
                                          new ObservableCollection<MyDataConcept>();

  foreach (var data in GetDates(year, month))
  {
    if (data.DayOfWeek.ToString() != "Saturday" && data.DayOfWeek.ToString() != "Sunday")
    {
     MyDataConcept kdc = new MyDataConcept(data.DayOfWeek.ToString(), data.Date);
     resultList.Add(kdc);
    }
  }
}
```

I don't have problem to display DayName = `data.DayOfWeek.ToString()`, only to **display correct DateTimeColumn = data.Date** as it showing now as: `09/03/2018 12:00:00 AM`.

I tried to convert as below:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(data.ToShortDateString());
```

or

```
var date = System.DateTime.ParseExact(data.ToShortDateString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", 
           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None);
```

but it's not working.

**UPDATE**:
 This is my XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyConceptItems}"
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you convert a DateTime to DateTime. Then, the formatting is gone. Try using a string:

```
var date = data.ToShortDateString();
```

If you really want to use DateTime inside DataGrid, then just the XAML definition of the column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DateTimeColumn, StringFormat=\{0:yyyy-MM-dd\}}" />
```

If you columns are auto-generated, i.e. you do not have column definitions in XAML, then you can handle event AutoGeneratingColumn of the data grid:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        e.Column = new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) { StringFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" }
        };
    }
}
```

And in XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyConceptItems}" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

Comment: but I need to pass "DateTime", not String

Comment: @4est Updated the answer for the case when you want to preserve DateTime as a type.

Comment: when I'm adding it between <DataGrid> ....</DataGrid> I got error...."Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource."

Comment: I had to use <DataGrid><DataGrid.Columns> then your input....but then was created "new column" - it's display ok but I don't want to add one more column

Comment: @4est You should be able to change the definition of existing columns. Maybe it will become more clear if you show your XAML.

Comment: I have just update my question - I wrote my current XAML for Grid

Comment: in my BuildDataConceptList method - where it should be run? or need I bind it to new button?

Comment: You should have a link to this event hadler in your XAML, see my update. Then, the event handler itself should be in code behind.